# getting 'Aborting' after git has pulled some files

Tags: git, git-pull

I use git for versioning, I am trying to pull code changes from the server. 
As i run 'git pull origin master', after pulling some files its showing me 'Aborting'.
Whats this about, I have been working on git past 3 months but no such thing happened. Is there something corrupted?

Also unable to 'git push' since all the files have not been pulled

its like:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    sites/all/modules/examples/form_example/form_example_tutorial.inc
    sites/all/modules/examples/form_example/form_example_wizard.inc
    sites/all/modules/examples/image_example/image_example.info
    sites/all/modules/examples/image_example/image_example.install
    sites/all/modules/examples/image_example/image_example.module
    sites/all/modules/examples/image_example/image_example.pages.inc
    sites/all/modules/examples/image_example/image_example.test
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/accordion.tpl.php
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/css/jsweights.css
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js/ajaxy.js
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js/black.js
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js/blue.js
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js/brown.js
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js/green.js
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js/purple.js
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js/red.js
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js_example.info
    sites/all/modules/examples/js_example/js_example.module
    sites/all/modules/examples/menu_example/menu_example.info
    sites/all/modules/examples/menu_example/menu_example.module
    sites/all/modules/examples/menu_example/menu_example.tes
Aborting
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the full output from `git pull` including the error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All those files it lists are untracked in your local branch, so if you do the merge, any changes you have made to those files will be irretrievably lost.  Therefore, git doesn't let you do the merge.

To fix it, either delete all those files from your working tree or add and commit them, depending on if you want to keep your local changes to them or not.

Comment: Is there not some git command that just says "I don't care about those files, overwrite them with the remote version"?

Comment: git clean -n will do a dry run (-n) of a clean operation, which will remove all non-tracked files from your local copy. If you agree, git clean -d will actually delete thosee files; then git fetch or git pull will succeed. (http://blog.saltriversystems.com/2011/11/git-untracked-files-problem/)

Comment: If you've added files already you can do a `git reset --hard master` to reset your local repository to its last pull or merge (at the `master` branch). After that it should go through, if not, you can also try cleaning the repo as suggested by PaulCalabro. I just tried it here and it worked, while before I was getting the mysterious aborting issue as listed in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Is the local branch tracked? In the .git folder there is a config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = //cunim/Repositories/AvaPA.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "dev"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/dev
```

There has to be an entry for the branch you are on for it to be pushed back

Heres a set of video tutorials on git we found very helpful

http://www.ava.co.uk/git